# Rust warp How to proxy request with json payload to another url by adding extra header?

Tags: rust, reqwest, rust-warp

How to add extra header like `access_token : jshaj_some_really_long_token` and also set content-type to `Content-Type: application/json` in warp post call?

Scenario in detail:

1. I want to create API using warp say the end point is `https://example.com/orders`
2. The type is post which needs a payload => `'{ "myid" : 12 , "price" : 23.2, "transaction" : "buy", "quantity" : 10 }'`
3. Now I want to use `reqwest` or any in built `warp` `http` client to send a request to another server endpoint say `https://api.example.com/orders` with the above post payload but with the new header which is `Content-Type: application/json` and `access-token: jshaj_some_really_long_token`

Please do share if there are some examples which are using warp and reqwest for post requests. Currently I am referring [this](https://github.com/halfzebra/rust-reqwest-warp-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`warp-reverse-proxy`](https://crates.io/crates/warp-reverse-proxy) crate for that (maintainer here :) )

You would have to compose the utilities inside to modify what you need as per the example:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let hello = warp::path!("hello" / String).map(|name| format!("Hello port, {}!", name));

    // // spawn base server
    tokio::spawn(warp::serve(hello).run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 8080)));

    let request_filter = extract_request_data_filter();
    let app = warp::path!("hello" / String)
        // build proxy address and base path data from current filter
        .map(|port| (format!("http://127.0.0.1:{}/", port), "".to_string()))
        .untuple_one()
        // build the request with data from previous filters
        .and(request_filter)
        .and_then(proxy_to_and_forward_response)
        .and_then(log_response);

    // spawn proxy server
    warp::serve(app).run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 3030)).await;
}
```

Notice that the forwarding of the request is done by the lib, if you actually want examples you can check the [source code](https://github.com/danielSanchezQ/warp-reverse-proxy) to investigate how it is done.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to use it, but could not understand where and how to add the header option.

Comment: @rahoolm, you have a warp filter there that you can compose with a headers filter and other extractors as needed. https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/filters/header/fn.header.html

Comment: I am having discussion with owner of warp-reverse-proxy module, seems like it could be helpful. I will post once I get a properly solution